# LiveCycle dynamic form that prints copies with different texts on each copy

Tags: pdf, livecycle, livecycle-designer, xfa

I need to create a dynamic form with adobe LiveCycle.
User enter the data in a form, and then, we need to generate a printable version of a document, with different copies of that printable version, and different texts on each copy, like "copy for you", "copy por bank", ....

Anyone knows how can I do that, in a simply and elegant way?

Comment: Your workflow looks very much like this: http://itextpdf.com/businessproces where XFA Worker ( http://itextpdf.com/product/XFA_worker ) first flattens the PDF (so that it can be consumed in PDF viewers other than Adobe Reader) and then postprocesses it (e.g. digital signature, watermark,...).

Comment: It's not an option, because it needs to use external aplications by the final user.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical business case. You can:

- Implement the business logic in your orchestration and render multiple copies of the same form with different data ( like the one you mentioned in your description) or
- You can make your template smart so that it creates multiple copies of each form and generate the templates with the data outlined above.

I hope this helps. Please let me know if you have any further questions or require clarification.

Thanks,
Armaghan.

Answer (score 0):

Add a **Print Button** in your from with **Presence** = Visible(Screen Only)(If you dont want to Print the Button in form). Then add a textfield at the place where you want to print "Customer Copy/Bank Copy". In my case, I placed a text field at the top right and named it "**Documenta**".
Then in the click script of print button, add following :

```
Documenta.rawValue = "Customer Copy"  
xfa.host.print(1, "0", (xfa.host.numPages -1).toString(), 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);  
Documenta.rawValue = "Bank Copy"  
xfa.host.print(1, "0", (xfa.host.numPages -1).toString(), 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

When you will press Print Button in the form, it will pop up print option 2 times consecutively having printed Customer Copy and Bank Copy, (without having Print Button printed on it).

In my Case, I wanted to print either 3 Copies, 2 Copies or 1 Copy(separate print button for each), so in 3 copies, I added 2 same extra lines with rawValue = "Transporter copy". And in 1 copy, I didnt want anything, so I kept only two lines with rawValue = "". You can use as many copies you want.

Download file from the link below. Print 2 Copies is pdf xml file(Form), BC is example for Bank Copy and CC is example for Customer Copy.

[Livecycle Designer Print 2 Copies - Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B8ka-2ksazsqYmtOQmpaNWtCbmc)